# PUSH: Unable to get GCM project number, run "ionic config set gcm_key your-gcm-id"

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework

I cannot send push notifications to android.
I updated to latest ionic cli 
I updated to latest ionic lib
After that also did:

```
ionic config build
```

and

```
ionic prepare android
```

my io-config.json has

```
{"app_id":"01e6d3ad","api_key":"some_secret_key","gcm_key":"142738311658"}
```

I've made `ionic config set gcm_key your-gcm-id` several time and replaced 'your-gcm-id' with my project ID.

but I still get this message:

```
PUSH: Unable to get GCM project number, run "ionic config set gcm_key your-gcm-id"
```

And when I try to register for ionic notification I also get:

```
$ionicPush:REGISTER_ERROR org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the problem is that Ionic framework had some changes :)

First of all some of the libraries like ionic-push and core were depricated and instead 'ionic-platform-web-client' should be used that replaces all the others.

In order to be able to install it you should update your ionic cli to the latest version.

**(Don't forget to remove links to ionic core and ionic push from your index.html)**

Also the registration code itself changed and you no longer waiting for event instead you should use the following code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    Ionic.io(); 

    var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    });
  });
```

---

Several additional points for people who might get issues:

1. Make sure you include PushNotification.js right after cordova.js
2. if you cant install push notification plugin with

   ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push

try installing it with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push
```

3. after removing plugins especially ionic core - make sure to run

   ionic config build

Answer (score 1):

Following the Ionic [documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/android-push-profiles) for Android, you must run the command:

```
ionic config set gcm_key <your-gcm-project-number>
```

In order to add the `projectNumber` to **.io-config.json**

Comment: Thanks elverde,
As you can see in my answer the problem wasn't missing gcm_key.

Comment: Hi @Lev have you tried seting the flag "dev_push":false (or true if you are in test mode)? run "ionic config set dev_push true" to set the environment

Answer (score 0):

Opening your `.io-config.json` file and putting quotes around the `gcm_key` value. after that try your commands.

see [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-service-push-client/issues/21) link

hope its work.

Comment: I appreciate your answer - but I have quotes arround gcm_key.
Also this issue should be solved in 1.6.4 and I'm using 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using your sender ID instead of your server key. The `gcm_key` of ionic configuration refers to the `server-key` provided by firebase. You can use

`ionic config set gcm_key <your-gcm-project-number>`

or add the value `server-key` to the key `gcm-key` in file `.io-config.json` that you can find in your ionic project directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I actually showed below what was my problem and how it resolved.